# How validate if a specific value was selected and store it in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, web, laravel-blade

I have this store function in my Controller, and I need to validate If **$type = "Texto"**, he create a normal text instead a Card.

[image]

This is my .blade view file, with the options, but even if I select 'Texto' he create a Card anyway, even use **@if($dashboard->type == "texto");**

[image]

This is the cards in application, I need in the **footer** have a text line If was selected in Form.

[image]

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: When you select  'Texto' your submit a form ? what is the data flow ? can you explain more please

Comment: Exactly, I submit a form and my route is /create..I was thinking in do another create function in my controller, but I will have to do another form, and I want to use the same form for the both options..

Comment: Good practice is, use code blocks instead of pictures in Question or answer

Comment: Thank you, I will use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare the `type` with `text` rather than `texto` as your option value is `text`. In your store function..

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->type == "text") {
        // code when texto is selected
    } else if($request->type == "card") {
        // code when card is selected
    }else {
        // code for handling other options
    }
}
```

And same goes for blade file. You have to compare `$dashboard->type` with `text` rather than `texto`.